# How to cast a Ratio< T > to a float in Rust (in a way that's compatible with type bounds)

Tags: rust, casting

Suppose you want to cast a `Ratio< isize >` to an `f64` in Rust, e.g.

```rust
use num::rational::Ratio;

pub fn foo() {
    let a = Ratio::new(1,1);
    let b = < cast a to f64 >;
}
```

What's the best way to do this?  Ideally it should be a trait method, for compatibility with type bounds.

#### Why this isn't obvious

The solution might be obvious to many experienced Rust users, but it's hard to find this in the documentation.  For example, running a text search for `f64` on the crates.ion page for [num::rational::Ratio](https://docs.rs/num/latest/num/rational/struct.Ratio.html) yields no hits.  A search for `float` only returns methods that convert to rationals from floats, not vice versa.  Beginners might also search for implementations of `From` and `Into` which turn up empty.  Finally, web search doesn't turn up a satisfying answer, and neither does chat GPT.  For example, one of the top hits just defines a function to [destructure](https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/2saclr/numrational_help/) and cast to floats.  This isn't to say that it's impossible to find an answer, but if you're unlucky then you might spend a lot more time looking than you want to.

Comment: Other than `ToPrimitive::to_f64()`, you can also use `let b = (*a.numer() as f64) / (*a.denom() as f64)`.

Comment: You can simply [search for the function signature](https://docs.rs/num/latest/num/rational/struct.Ratio.html?search=Ratio%20-%3E%20f64)

Comment: I restored the OP's explanatory text, because it provides important context that shows that they did research before asking the question. Without it the question (and the self-answer) might indeed appear trivial and unnecessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Solution 1 (general)

Updating to highlight one of the comments: crates.io lets you search for a function signature.  This solution can be used in much broader contexts.

#### Solution 2 (specific)

As noted in the [issues](https://github.com/rust-num/num-rational/issues/61) for the git repository, there's a trait `ToPrimitive` which provides the desired functionality:

```rust
use num::{rational::Ratio, ToPrimitive};

pub fn foo() {
    let a = Ratio::new(1,1);
    let b: Option< f64 > = a.to_f64();
}
```

This plays well with bounds:

```rust
use num::{rational::Ratio, ToPrimitive};


struct MakeFloats< T: ToPrimitive >(T);

impl < T: ToPrimitive > MakeFloats< T > {
    fn make_float(&self) -> f64 {
        self.0.to_f64().unwrap()
    }
}

fn main() {
    let a: Ratio<i64> = Ratio::new(1,1);
    let b = MakeFloats(a);
}
```